# Add and Remove elements of the table using array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my index and js file. When I click on the first table row it works but when I click on it again, it doesn't work. It works only one time for one table. Same thing is happening in the second table. I have also given the class name in the js file. Why it does not consider class name. Please explain it also.

```js
var t1 = [];
var t2 = [];
$('.table2 tr').each(function(row, tr) {
  t2[row] = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
});
$('.table1 tr').each(function(row, tr) {
  t1[row] = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
});
$(".addRow").on("click", function() {
  var $delete = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
  t2.push($delete);
  t1.splice($.inArray($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(), t1), 1);
  var tbody2 = $('.body2');
  $(".table2 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
    tr.append('<td>' + t2[i] + '</td>');
  }
  var tbody1 = $('.body1');
  $(".table1 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody1);
    tr.append('<td>' + t1[i] + '</td>');
  }
});

$(".deleteRow").on("click", function() {
  var $add = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
  t1.push($add);
  t2.splice($.inArray($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(), t2), 1);
  var tbody1 = $('.body1');
  $(".table1 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody1);
    tr.append('<td>' + t1[i] + '</td>');
  }
  var tbody2 = $('.body2');
  $(".table2 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
    tr.append('<td>' + t2[i] + '</td>');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table Manipulation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    >
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 available">
      <label>Available Members</label>
      <table class="table table-bordered table1">
        <tbody class="body1">
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Tabrez</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Akash</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Keshav</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Harsh</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 selected">
      <label>Selected Members</label>
      <table class="table table-bordered table2">
        <tbody class="body2">
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Varun</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Shanu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Salvi</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Piyush</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="table.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by clicking on second  table row?

Comment: I just want to add an element of the first table to the second on click and second table element on the first on click on the element

Comment: Still not clear enough.....I have posted an answer.....Please see that if it helps....

Comment: Do you want to move forth and back from available to selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach event (`click`) by using jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Some possible changes you can make:

```
$("tbody").on("click",".addRow", function() {......
```

And

```
$("tbody").on("click",".deleteRow", function() {......
```

Also I think you are mistakenly adding `class="addRow"` instead of `class="deleteRow"` in the second `for` loop of `.deleteRow` click in the second table:

```
var tr = $('<tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
```

```js
var t1 = [];
var t2 = [];
$('.table2 tr').each(function(row,tr){
    t2[row]=$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
});
$('.table1 tr').each(function(row,tr){
    t1[row]=$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
});
$("tbody").on("click",".addRow", function() {
  var $delete = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
  t2.push($delete);
  t1.splice($.inArray($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(),t1),1);
  var tbody2 = $('.body2');
  $(".table2 tr").remove();
  for(var i = 0;i < t2.length;i++){
    var tr = $('<tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
    tr.append('<td>' + t2[i] + '</td>');
  }
  var tbody1 = $('.body1');
  $(".table1 tr").remove();
  for(var i = 0;i < t1.length;i++){
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody1);
    tr.append('<td>' + t1[i] + '</td>');
  }
});

$("tbody").on("click",".deleteRow", function() {
  var $add = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
  t1.push($add);
  t2.splice($.inArray($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(),t2),1);
  var tbody1 = $('.body1');
  $(".table1 tr").remove();
  for(var i = 0;i < t1.length;i++){
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody1);
    tr.append('<td>' + t1[i] + '</td>');
  }
  var tbody2 = $('.body2');
  $(".table2 tr").remove();
  for(var i = 0;i < t2.length;i++){
    var tr = $('<tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
    tr.append('<td>' + t2[i] + '</td>');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Manipulation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 available">
    <label>Available Members</label>
    <table class="table table-bordered table1">
      <tbody class="body1">
        <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
          <td>Tabrez</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
          <td>Akash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
          <td>Keshav</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
          <td>Harsh</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 selected">
    <label>Selected Members</label>
    <table class="table table-bordered table2">
      <tbody class="body2">
        <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
          <td>Varun</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
          <td>Shanu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
          <td>Salvi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
          <td>Piyush</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="table.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why there is change in color from green to red in available members when item coming from selected to available?

Comment: @dhaker, those are OP's code and logic......I have changed only the mentioned lines of code.... thanks.

Comment: This is not working. case - remove all elements from available and try to add into it, we cannot add more than one

Comment: @dhaker, the question needs to be updated with the points you are mentioning here......

Comment: @tarvez ansari, please notice the update in the question (The addition of third point).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not specifying the `selector` in `.on()` function.

> If `selector` is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to
>   as direct.
>   When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated.
>
> An event-delegation (direct) approach attaches an event handler to
>   only one element, the `tbody`.
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`

So you need to provided a selector for `.on()` function as below.

```
$('.table1').on('click', '.addRow', function() {})

$('.table2').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {})
```

> Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process
>   events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a
>   later time.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Also, you have an error in `deleteRow` functionality and fixed in below complete example.

```js
var t1 = [];
var t2 = [];

$('.table2 tr').each(function(row, tr) {
  t2[row] = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
});

$('.table1 tr').each(function(row, tr) {
  t1[row] = $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
});

$('.table1').on('click', '.addRow', function() {
  var $delete = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
  t2.push($delete);
  t1.splice($.inArray($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(), t1), 1);
  var tbody2 = $('.body2');
  $(".table2 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
    tr.append('<td>' + t2[i] + '</td>');
  }
  var tbody1 = $('.body1');
  $(".table1 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody1);
    tr.append('<td>' + t1[i] + '</td>');
  }
});

$('.table2').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
  var $add = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
  t1.push($add);
  
  t2.splice($.inArray($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(), t2), 1);
  var tbody1 = $('.body1');
  
  $(".table1 tr").remove();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody1);
    tr.append('<td>' + t1[i] + '</td>');
  }
  var tbody2 = $('.body2');
  $(".table2 tr").remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer"/>').appendTo(tbody2);
    tr.append('<td>' + t2[i] + '</td>');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table Manipulation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    >
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 available">
      <label>Available Members</label>
      <table class="table table-bordered table1">
        <tbody class="body1">
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Tabrez</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Akash</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Keshav</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addRow" style="color:#32c24d;cursor:pointer">
            <td>Harsh</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 selected">
      <label>Selected Members</label>
      <table class="table table-bordered table2">
        <tbody class="body2">
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Varun</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Shanu</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Salvi</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="deleteRow" style="color:#f44336;cursor:pointer;">
            <td>Piyush</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="table.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```